# Is it neccessary to detach all my Firestore listeners when signing out?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

### Introduction

I have multiple listeners on different screens of my App. The signing out is implemented in a child component of my Profile screen, and as I am not using redux I have to pass every single listener (actually I have all of them stored on the ref of a parent component) to it for detaching them before signing out.

### Question

This is not really easy to handle, as I have to pass multiple listeners from children to a common parent as props and then to the SignOut component... Taking a long tour of the component tree.

Is it really neccesary to detach all my Firebase Listeners before signing out? What could happen if not (bugs or something...)?

Pd: I am using the ["Protected routes"](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/) pattern for navigation

### CODE

> Sign Out Component

```
const SignOut = withFirebase(function SignOut(props) {
   // ... stuff
   const signOut = () => {
    const { firebase, onSignOut } = props;

    // Do the neccessary stuff before signing out
    onSignOut();

    // Change the authentication state
    firebase.signOut();
  };
  // ... stuff
};
```

> Profile Screen Component (Direct Parent of the Sign Out component)

```
...
const {attachListener, detachListeners} = props;

// ... code attaching a new firestore listener
// ... stuff

return (
   ...
   <SignOut detachListeners={detachListeners} />
)
```

> Common parent (which contains a ref to all listeners)

```
 ...
 const listeners = useRef([]).current;

 const attachListener = (listener) => listeners.push(listener);

 const dettachListeners = () => listeners.forEach(listener => listener());


 useEffect(() => {
    // cleanup
    return () => { 
       detachListeners(); 
    }
 }, []);


 return (
     <>
        <Profile attachListener={attachListener} detachListener={detachListener} />
        <OtherComponentWithListeners1 attachListener={attachListener} />
        <OtherComponentWithListeners2 attachListener={attachListener} />
     </>
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it really neccesary to detach all my Firebase Listeners before signing out?

That's entirely up to you to determine for your specific case.

> What could happen if not (bugs or something...)?

You could leak a listener that continues to receive updates long after those updates are useful.  This would be a waste of money and bandwidth.  If you want to avoid waste, remove all listener before they become useless in your app.